# Entity Framework orderby does not update datagrid

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, sqlite, sql-order-by

I'm new to C#, MVVM, WPF and Entity Framework

my problem is, if I order the reading of the database (orderby) the datagrid will not be changed if I add a new row. if i do not order the reading it works.

so addition infos:

my database looks like this

```
Table Konto
KontoID
KontoName

Table Buchung
KontoID
BuchungsID
Name
BuchDate
```

after the Konto is loaded it will load all related Buchungen

```
 _entityKontoView = new CollectionViewSource();
 _entityBuchungView = new CollectionViewSource();
 // Loads the Konto
 _entityKontoView.Source = _database.Konto;

 _entityKontoView.View.CurrentChanged += (x, y) =>
 {
   _entityBuchungView.Source = ((Konto)_entityKontoView.View.CurrentItem).Buchung
            //.OrderBy(date => date.BuchDate)
                //.ThenBy(buchnr => buchnr.BuchungsID)
                ;
 };
 _entityKontoView.View.Refresh();
```

when i do now an `OrderBy` the datagrid will not be update after new inserted Row

i open the the database entity as follow:

```
public static databaseEntities _database = new databaseEntities();
```

my XAML binding on DataGrid:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding EntityBuchungsView.View}"
```

and my columns binding ;

```
Binding="{Binding Name}"
```

as far i used `_database.Buchung.AddObject(test);` and then `_database.SaveChanges();` and my DataGrid got updated.

what do i false?

Comment: You probably need to call `.ToList()` after the orderby (or any other call that enumerates the object, like `AsEnumerable()`). `OrderBy()` retuns a deferred execution object.

Comment: just tried this, but nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone have the same problem like me

i did implement a new method for refreshing the view:

```
public static void RefreshView(CollectionViewSource entity)
{
    entity.View.Refresh();
}
```

then it worked